# What are possible ways to upload a photo to facebook through the graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

What are the possible ways to upload photos to facebook through the graph API? I know you can do it by posting to me/photos. Are there any other ways that photos can be uploaded through the graph API?

Answer (score 0):

You can also upload a photo alongside a Post.

From [Graph API Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/):

> We support writing the following types of objects:
>
> Method: /PROFILE_ID/feed
> Description: Publish a new post on the given profile's feed/wall
>
> Arguments: message, **picture**, link, name, caption,
> description, source, place, tags

And [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) is the the 'Post' object in more detail.